# How call a Windows program (.exe file) from Python 3

Tags: python, .htpasswd

I know this may seem a common question, yes, there are many questions similar to mine and yes, apparently there are solutions but the problem is that I tried them but they do not work.
This is my code:

```py
def testOne():
    output = subprocess.run(["htpasswd.exe", "-nb", "spock", "volerevolare"], capture_output=True)
    print( output )
    print("out: <{o}>".format(o=output.stdout.decode()))   
    print( "return code: dec {d:d}   hex {h:X}".format(d=output.returncode, h=output.returncode) ) 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this is its output:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['htpasswd.exe', '-nb', 'spock', 'volerevolare'], returncode=3221225781, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')
out: <>
return code: dec 3221225781   hex C0000135
```

so in my opinion after looking at the error code I think that my little applications does not work and htpasswd.exe is not executed.
O.S. is Win 7, normal user (not admin user).
What I missed?
Thanks,
Massimo

Comment: Can you run `htpasswd.exe` from your terminal? You may need to provide a full file path to that executable.

Comment: yes, from the terminal it works

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem found, I have also cygwin installed so it was a problem related to PATH. Copying locally the right htpasswd.exe (Windows 10 version) solved the problem. The htpasswd windows version is already installed in Win 10, for previous release I verified it works since Win 7 it is downloadable here: https://www.exefiles.com/it/exe/htpasswd-exe/